# Loading mini-interfaces with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm in the process of creating a revised version of a CMS I've made for a few sites.

In this redesigned version, there is a list on the left, showing you different sections you can manage (text, photo gallery etc.). On the right, I want to load the appropriate UI via AJAX when the user selects an item.

I started off by simply making a request to various files, and shoving the HTML in a div, like so:

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
    map = {"text":"txt_interface.php","gallery":"gallery_interface.php"};

    $('#left_pane li').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (map[id].length) {
            // show loading stuff etc.
            var url = 'ajax/'+map[id];
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    $('#right_content').html(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, I then realized that certain pages would require external JS (e.g. tinyMCE). So, I tried various solutions such as passing the js references down in JSON separately and using `$.getScript`, but it all became horribly over-complicated.

Preferably without using frames, what is the simplest way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you give us some specific examples of what JS needs to be run and how?  It seems you could pull in js files in your main page and then run what you have to when pulling in the right content, but it is hard to give direction when there is not a specific example.

Comment: @BenL in this specific instance I gave in the question I require the tinyMCE source file (external), and a function to be called once the content has loaded on tinyMCE `tinyMCE.init();` - I pass a few parameters into that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your JavaScript in a block that you can pull-out in your AJAX callback function and `eval` it (I know Google does something similar to this to defer parsing of certain JavaScript):

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                var tmp    = res.split("{script}"),
                    code   = tmp[1].split("{/script}")[0];
                eval(code);
                $('#right_content').html(tmp[0]);
            }
        });
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HReW/

This assumes that you put `{script}`/`{/script}` in place of the regular `<script>`/`</script>` tags and that the JavaScript block comes at the end of the content pulled in via AJAX.

Comment: this is nice - although I have heard bad things about eval :/ - also it doesn't solve the problem of external JS

Comment: for now I'm just including all the external scripts I need in the main page - but this for loading inline scripts works really nicely - thanks :)